# View invalidation

Tags: android

I have a custom view and a button in a linear layout.

If I press the button I get an `onDraw` request in my view code, and if I release the button I do get another `onDraw`.  Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Screenshot of the app can be seen [here](http://home-5.worldonline.nl/~jdekeij/android.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is behaving as designed.

Comment: Agreed. There can be listeners hooked to every event which can "invalidate" a view, therefore, the request from parent to the view to redraw itself.